# Not able to add products on magento HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Getting error on my magento website. 
HTTP ERROR 500 on a[image]dding products.

Attached my error log files.

[16-Feb-2017 09:19:24 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getResourceCollection() on a non-object in /home/allinoll/public_html/smnutritions.com/includes/src/Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Countryofmanufacture.php on line 48

Comment: I think you have missed some attributes of products. also let me know this error is occurred in frontend or in backend?

Comment: its only in beckend.

Comment: when you add new product or edit the existing product?

Comment: yes. and now checkout option is even not working.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Issues Fixed. I just deleted all the files from includes except config.php and htaccess and now its working perfectly even performance also improved.